# How to make the eclipse IDE to build faster

Tags: eclipse, ide, carbide

I am using Eclipse for development. However, it's is taking too much time to build. 
It hangs when the percentage of build gets to 78. It shows "refreshing workspace" several times. That eats up lots of time.

How can I make Eclipse faster?

Comment: See this eclipse.ini for a faster eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590

Answer (score 4):

1. Increase the start-up memory as mentioned by thamaria
2. Disable spell check of eclipse
3. Disable the plugins which you never use it (myln etc)
4. Disable auto build.

This link might help you

http://pakkatechies.blogspot.com/2011/07/making-eclipse-ide-faster.html

Answer (score 3):

There are many possibilities to tune Eclipse.

First, when Eclipse is hanging up you should start Eclipse with some arguments and give it more memory. Use: **eclipse -vmargs -Xms256m -Xmx1024m** or even more.

**EDIT**: "eclipse -vmargs -Xms256m -Xmx1024m" is the commandline command with which you can start Eclipse (well, depending on your OS). For that you either need to have eclipse in your environement path or you will have to use an absolute path to your eclipse executable file. Under Windows systems you may use for example "C:\Programme\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xms256m -Xmx1024m". You could f.e. create a short-cut with this command.

Second: If possible you can use several workspaces for your eclipse projects if they are not connected to each other. When using other projects than the ones located in your actual workspace switch the workspace to the one you desire. That way eclipse does not need to load all contents at startup and will therefor start much faster.

Third: You can disable the "build workspace" Option.  Go to "project" --> and **uncheck "build automatically"**.

Comment: can you please tell me how to give the argument which you have mentioned d above to the eclipse.. i am very new to it.

Comment: in my project settings "build automatically" is disabled i checked just now.. still it shows "refreshing workspace"

Comment: Hey "refresh automatically" option i have unchecked.. so "refreshing workspace" is not coming..one problem solved thanks.. but please tell how to put those argument to eclipse so that i can make build some more faster.

Comment: Well, it probably won't make the build faster, but it will help you to prevent a crash related to memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

In the project build properties, under behavior tag, check the 'Enable parallel build' box.